# remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, gitlab

Tengo unos miembros agregados al proyecto como *developer* pero no pueden realizar `git push`, el error que muestra es el siguiente:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/edwardbrian96/cartravel.git/'

Comment: Si es que inicias sesión en gitlab desde github entra a configuraciones en gitlab y establece una contraseña, cuando se inicia desde github no se puede autenticar ya que no hay una contraseña, tal vez ese sea tu problema.

Comment: @FernandoJavierLeón si agrego contraseña pero todavia no se puede

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no tienes configurado el acceso por http(s) correctamente. Gitlab permite siempre operaciones de lectura por https, incluso si el protocolo está desactivado. Esto causaría un fallo de autenticación en caso de intentar una operación de escritura como el push que comentas.

Mira la configuración de acceso al repositorio como dice en la [documentación.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#:%7E:text=Git%20access%20protocols%3A-,Sign%20in%20to%20GitLab%20as%20a%20user%20with%20Administrator%20role,Select%20Save%20changes.,-When%20both%20SSH)